# Finding Basis of Kernel $\Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> The linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^4→\Bbb R^2$ defined by
>   $$T(x,y,z,s)=(2x−2y+z+2s,4y−4x−5s)$$
>
> Give a basis for the kernel of T.
>
> Basis of $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ is { ... }
>
> Enter your answers as comma separated lists of vectors,
>
> for example $(1,2,3),(4,5,6)$

So, I have this question. I solved some questions similar to this but they were $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$ and I could eliminate some letters for example: I found $x(-1,0,1)$ and eliminated $y$ and $z$, but in this one, I couldn't eliminate any letters so I'm stuck. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Same idea though, just more letters. You must have done row reduction (Gaussian Elimination)? You will probably have some free variables that you cannot determine. The vector multiples of these variables are your basis.

Comment: Just simply apply Gaussian elimination.

Comment: I did the calculations and got this basis $(1,1,0,0)$,$(-5,0,1/2,1)$

Comment: I tried to submit this answer to my question but it seems that it's incorrect.

Comment: Oh, it was -5/4 instead of -5 in second basis, Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to find the elements $(x,y,z,s)$ of the kernel. That is find the elements  $(x,y,z,s)$ such that:
\begin{cases} 2x-2y+z+2s = 0 \\ 4y-4x-5s=0\end{cases}

Solving that, we get:

$$x = t-\frac{5}{4}w\quad ; \quad z=\frac{1}{2}w$$

Where $t,w \in \mathbb{R}$

So the elements in the kernel are:
\begin{align}
(x,y,z,s)&=\left( t-\frac{5}{4}w,t,\frac{1}{2}w,w\right) \\
&=(t,t,0,0)+\left( -\frac{5}{4}w,0,\frac{1}{2}w,w\right) \\
&=t(1,1,0,0)+w\left( -\frac{5}{4},0,\frac{1}{2},1\right)
\end{align}

Then you need check that $(1,1,0,0)$ and $\left( -\frac{5}{4},0,\frac{1}{2},1\right)$ are linearly independent and generate the kernel.